# Problem on casting objects to array of a model in Angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript

Here is my service code:

```
export class ProductListService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {

  }
  getProducts(): Observable<IResponse> {
    return this.httpClient.get<IResponse>('https://localhost:7127/Product/GetProductList');
  }
}
```

and here is my component:

```
  getProducts(): void {
    this.productsService.getProducts()
      .subscribe((response: IResponse) => {
       this.products = <Product[]>response.data;
      })
  }
```

Which Product and IResponse are models:

```
export interface Product {
  Id: string;
  Title: string;
  Description: string;
  ImageUri: string;
  CategoryId: string;
}

export interface IResponse {
  data: object;
  status: number;
}
```

When I get data from the api, it returns data as follow:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "e15",
         "title": "LED TV 42 inch ",
         "description": "-",
         "imageUri": "C:\\wwwroot/cdn\\e15.jpg",
         "categoryId": "tv"
      },
      {
         "id": "e16",
         "title": "LED TV 52 inch ",
         "description": "-",
         "imageUri": "C:\\wwwroot/cdn\\e16.jpg",
         "categoryId": "tv"
      }
   ],
   "status": 200
}
```

I want to put the data into my `products` variable. How could I do this?

Comment: Can you change the interfaces to remove the initial capitalization on each property name? That's the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Sean Chase. Change the casing on your model. You also might want to cast the data property on the IResponse interface to Product[] (as a side note, interfaces don't start with I. That's a C# convention).

Are you using the products property in the template HTML? If so, you can use the pipe async syntax and replace the products property with an Observable<Product[]>. Here's an example

```
// models.ts
export interface Product {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    imageUri: string;
    categoryId: string;
}

export interface IResponse {
    data: Product[];
    status: number;
}



// product-list.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { map, Observable, of, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { IResponse, Product } from './models';
import { ProductListService } from './products-list.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'product-list',
    template: `
        <div *ngFor="let product of products$ | async">
            <div>Id: {{ product.id }}</div>
            <div>Title: {{ product.title }}</div>
            <div>Description: {{ product.imageUri }}</div>
            <div>CategoryId: {{ product.categoryId }}</div>
        </div>
    `
})
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {
    products$: Observable<Product[]> = of([]);

    constructor(private productsListService: ProductListService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.products$ = this.productsListService.getProducts().pipe(map((res: IResponse) => res.data));
    }
}


// product-list.service.ts
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { IResponse, Product } from './models';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ProductListService {
    // constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

    getProducts(): Observable<IResponse> {
        // return this.httpClient.get<IResponse>('https://localhost:7127/Product/GetProductList');
        return of({
            data: [
                {
                    id: '1',
                    title: 'title-1',
                    description: 'description-1',
                    imageUri: '/images/image-1.jpg',
                    categoryId: '1'
                } as Product,
                {
                    id: '2',
                    title: 'title-2',
                    description: 'description-2',
                    imageUri: '/images/image-2.jpg',
                    categoryId: '2'
                } as Product,
            ],
            status: 200
        });
    }
}
```